# Facing problem while reading date time in java from excel by converting date into String Format then parsing it

Tags: java, datetime, apache-poi, datetime-format

Trying to store date time from excel to setter using poi and LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter.

```
    DateTimeFormatter format=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime 
    dateObj=LocalDateTime.parse(row.getCell(2).getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toString(),format);
    dto.setDate(dateObj);
```

The output is:

```
    java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-01-22T00:00' could not be parsed at index 2
```

Please advise me what to do? In the excel file the date is stored in 1/22/2023 12:00:00 AM

Comment: What does `.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()` do? What's the return type? If you receive `LocalDateTime` from `.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()` then what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

Comment: getLocalDateTimeCellValue() returns LocalDateTime object from a excel cell value

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense if dto#date is of type `LocalDateTime`. LocalDateTime doesn't store any preferable format, but only stores the value (LocalDate and LocalTime). When you do `.getLocalDateTimeCellValue().toString()` you basically transform `LocalDateTime` to `String` with default ISO formatter and then again try to transform it into the `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `DateTimeFormatter` for the wrong purpose. Instead of formatting a `LocalDateTime` object, you are trying to parse a string unnecessarily. You need a formatted `String` which you can do as follows:

```
LocalDateTime dateObj = row.getCell(2).getLocalDateTimeCellValue();
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = dateObj.format(format);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I want to store it in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format in pojo class object, same as excel data

Comment: @TathagataDasgupta - I got confused initially thinking that you wanted to parse a string. I have updated my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: @TathagataDasgupta No you don’t. You want to use the correct data type in your POJO, that is, `LocalDateTime`. You want to format it in your user interface, not in your data model.